# SQL2012 UDF for all DateTime format conversions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to create a user defined Function that accepts a date input
and a date format input and results in a properly formatted date.

Ex: UDF('7/22', 'Internation')
OUTPUT: 22/7/2012

I need to implement all types of date formatting, or at least as much as possible. I think there should be at least 40 different types.

I've found solutions online that don't really work.

Does anyone have a function like this or can point me in the right direction. I'm pretty new to sql so writing this from scratch would take me until next week!

Comment: You want the UDF to assume the year is the current year? What if today is Jan 1 and the date passed is 12/29?

Comment: A multitude of problems are just waiting to hit you the moment you start treating dates as strings. Ideally, strings should be converted to dates as early as possible in your input processing, and dates converted to strings as late as possible in output processing. In the DB, dates should always be dates, and so the DB is the wrong place to be doing this kind of formatting.